# Vora Manager 1.3 log rotation

Tags: vora

Is there any log rotation in Vora 1.3? After 2 months of running Vora 1.3 I realized I'm almost of disk space on my nodes because /var/log/vora-manager is like 46 Gb. So I had to stop it, kill the logs and restart.
But maybe I missed some setting?

Edit 1: The log file is supposed to be stored in /var/log/vora/vora-manager, not the folder I mentioned above, but still I saw a huge log file there. The file /var/log/vora-manager is also mentioned in the line 178 of control.py script that is supposed to start a worked vora-manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right -- the vora-manager log file is not written into the standard /var/log/vora directory, instead it is written to /var/log/vora-manager. This has been corrected in Vora 1.4.

The logs should be rotating based on the `vora_manager_log_max_file_size` variable which is also set in Ambari.

Something must have gone wrong whenever vora tries to rotate the logs. I propose you search through your log file for the following line and see if it is followed by some kind of error:

> vora.vora-manager-master: [c.740b0d26] : Running['sudo', '-i', '-u',
>   'root', '/usr/sbin/logrotate', '/etc/logrotate.d/vora-manager-master']

You can also change the verbosity of the logger by setting the `vora_manager_log_level` config variable in Ambari from INFO to WARNING. Be ware this will hide the log rotation log messages.